# What does “[variable] {…}” mean?

Tags: c++, constexpr

What does return [value] is supposed to do.

```
constexpr int Increment(int value) 
{
    return [value] { return value + 1; }();
};
```

Comment: Why use a lambda expression here?

Comment: OK got it this is unnamed constexpr lambda inside function ....to evaluate it at compile time. I was confused with syntax.
Increment(10);

Comment: Reopened. This is not just a question about what a lambda expression does. It's about the use of a lambda expression that's written and immediately evaluated, and whether that's appropriate.

Comment: @PeteBecker: It's a question that can be answered by informing the user of what a lambda expression in C++ is. It therefore qualifies as a duplicate. And no, the question does not ask about whether this is "appropriate"; it's clearly about the meaning of the grammatical constructs involved.

Comment: @NicolBolas -- no. The question is about writing a lambda expression and immediately calling it, rather than simply writing the code that's inside the lambda. What does using a lambda expression accomplish that `return value + 1;` doesn't do?

Comment: lambda expression i know but was confused with the syntax inside function as why () at the end of  }.

Comment: In what context did you find this code?

Comment: Duplicate or Needs More Focus. I favor the duplicate, as it might lead to a question with better focus after the "What is this?" is cleared. ("Why is a lambda used here?", "How does this work with constexpr?", ..)

Comment: @mkrieger1 — you should re-post your follow-up question

Comment: @PeteBecker I undeleted and updated my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63767805/what-is-the-significance-of-returning-the-return-value-of-a-lambda-expression-fr).

Answer (score 1):

This code demonstrates a feature of c++ that a lamda can be made constexpr. Which is not possible before c++17. there is lamda expression called while return

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int Increment(int value) {
    return [value] { return value + 1; }();
};


int main()
{
    Increment(10);
    static_assert(11 == Increment(10), "Increment does not work correctly");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Would the code work the same if the body of `Increment` was simply `return value + 1;`?

Comment: Honestly, I don't see much value in this kind of questions. We have no way to guess what specific language feature the author intended to demonstrate.