# What is the significance of returning the return value of a lambda expression from a function?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, constexpr

Since C++17 [it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420085/is-constexpr-supported-with-lambda-functions-expressions) to use a lambda expression in a `constexpr` function.

In the related document [*Wording for constexpr lambda*](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/P0170R1.pdf) this code example is shown:

> ```
> constexpr int AddEleven(int n) {
>     return [n] { return n + 11; }();
> }
> ```

Is this just a toy example to demonstrate the language feature, or is there an actual use case where this code has a different behaviour than the following code?

```
constexpr int AddEleven(int n) {
    return n + 11;
}
```

What would be the benefit of using a lambda expression in this case?

Comment: I haven't followed recent developments in the language, so I'm not intimately familiar with `constexpr` or lambdas. But my immediate reaction is that if these two versions of the function behave differently, there's something seriously wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately-invoked lambdas are useful to provide a statement-friendly scope within an expression, typically to initialize `const` variables in a more complex way than constructor parameters permit:

```
auto const v = [&] {
    std::vector<int> v;

    // do some stuff
    for(/*...*/)
        v.push_back(/*...*/);

    return v;
}();
```

A `return` statement must already appears in a scope, so there's not a huge benefit to combining it with the above pattern. I could, however imagine it used to clarify an early-out condition which requires such an initialization:

```
if(/* some corner case */)
    return [&] {
        std::vector<int> v;
    
        // do some stuff
        for(/*...*/)
            v.push_back(/*...*/);
    
        return v;
    }();
```

... compared to:

```
if(/* some corner case */) {
    std::vector<int> v;
    
    // do some stuff
    for(/*...*/)
        v.push_back(/*...*/);
    
    return v;
}
```

... where the `return` is further away from the condition.

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the benefit of using a lambda expression in this case?

There's no benefit.

It's simple and obvious what it does, which serves the purpose of being an example of *valid* code. In much the same way no-one needs a program that outputs "Hello World" to a console, but there are hundreds of uses of that in example code.

Answer (score -3):

```
This code demonstrates a feature of c++ that a lamda can be made constexpr. Which is not possible before c++17.
This code will not work before c++17.

#include <iostream>

constexpr int Increment(int value) {
    return [value] { return value + 1; }();
};


int main()
{
    Increment(10);
    static_assert(11 == Increment(10), "Increment does not work correctly");

    return 0;

}
```